# Проблема XOR (двухслойный перспептрон) с 2 ортогональными прямыми

Tags: математика, машинное-обучение, xor

Задача: W1,W2 ортогональны, W1 = (1,0), W2 = (0,1)
Как геометрически устроены 2 части, на которые персептрон делит плоскость?
Можно ли решить проблему XOR при

- X1 = (-1,-1) = -1
- X4 = (1,1) = -1
- X2 = (-1,1) = 1
- X3 = (1,-1) = 1

Мне казалось, что персептрон разделит примерно как "+" или "х", но получилась система, которая не решается. Надо нарисовать графически, почему не вышло разделение ортогональными прямыми.
Вычисления на фото.[image: Двуслойный персептрон проблема XOR]

Comment: Пара возможных ответов: `R( R(x+y+1) + R(-x-y+1) -1)` или `R( R(x-y+1) + R(-x+y+1) -1 )`, где R-элемент - функция sign. Система не решается, потому что сильно недоопределена. Проще, нарисовать на графике точек пару линий, которые должны соотвествовать нейронам первого уровня, а по графическому решению уже строить уравнение.

Comment: @Chorkov Спасибо, но как понимаю если отдельно подставлять только в R( R(x+y+1) + R(-x-y+1) -1), то я получаю нужные мне числа (для х1,х4 = -1, х2,х3 = 1). Или здесь совокупность и рассматривается? Просто визуально без вычислений мне представляется, что можно разделить ортогональными прямыми, но я не понимаю как их графически вывести в соответствии решению.

Comment: Ортогональными прямыми - нельзя. Потому что нейроны не умеют XOR. Они могут OR / AND  / NOT / NOT+AND / NOT+OR. Поэтому XOR можно собрать толькко из двух слоев нейронов, но у вас после разреза прямыми останется только один слой. Значит вместо ортогональных прямых нужно использовать, например, параллельные прямые.

Comment: @Chorkov а какой график может вывести например программа, если я захочу задать разделение ортогональными? Или в принципе ничего

Comment: Никакой. (1) Вы не сожмите заставить программу использовать именно ортогональные прямые. (2) если все-таки сожмите, то она не найдет решения.

Comment: @Chorkov спасибо вам большое за пояснения!